# Detect collisons only on the border of a collider,How to detect collisions only on the border of a collider but not inside?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a 2D game and I want to implement two game objects with circular colliders to detect collisions following say an object is travelling from Point A to Point B then -

**See the image for details**

Thanks for the help

[image: Click Here for Image]

Comment: you could have 2 circle colliders so that if in a but not b, its on the edge, else its in the middle and thats fine, by having b set something to true on enter and false on exit

Comment: What about edge ccolliders? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-EdgeCollider2D.html

Comment: Edge colliders seems to be not working.While using edge colliders no collisions are being detected while exiting the object

Comment: @BugFinder using 2 concentric circluar colliders works but i want to know if i can implement using this way by just using one circular collider for every object.

Comment: Possibly but you seem to be stuck on one idea not a solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest answer is to just make a polygon collider 2D that looks like a ring, like so but without the gap and much thinner:

[image]

Then you can use [`OnTriggerStay2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html) to run the code you'd like to run on collision.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I already thought of that but i just want to know whether i can implement it using circular colliders.